# MomentJS Date.now() format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

What is the correct way to format this when using MomentJS's `fromNow()` functionality?

The date was generated using Javascripts `Date.now()` function.

```
Thu Nov 19 2015 19:58:03 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

My first attempt was this.

```
var date = Thu Nov 19 2015 19:58:03 GMT+0000 (GMT);

var parsed = moment(date, "dd MMM d YYYY h:mm:ss").fromNow();
```

But I'm quite sure that **dd MMM d YYYY h:mm:ss** isn't the correct way to format this.

Comment: `Date.now()` give epoch time, eg: `1447967182687`

Comment: You know you forgot the quotes on `var date = Thu Nov 19...`?

Comment: Yeah, it's sort of a placeholder. In it's actual use, I'm using a database query.

Comment: `moment("Thu Nov 19 2015 19:58:03 GMT+0000 (GMT)").fromNow()` ?

Comment: Oh, wow. What a silly mistake. I thought I had to specify the format of the date I was parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
var date = "Thu Nov 19 2015 19:58:03 GMT+0000 (GMT)";
moment(date).fromNow(); // 1 hour ago
```

See: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/